# How to temporarily change text color with beamer?

Tags: beamer, color

I have the following code. I used `\onslide` to reveal some colored numbers in an array. However, after I reveal the number, I want it to turn back to black, instead of remaining that color. How can I accomplish this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{
\center
1 \ \
\Longstack{1 \onslide<6->{1}} \ \
\onslide<5->{2} \ \
\Longstack{1 \onslide<4->{1} \onslide<6->{1}} \ \
\onslide<5->{3} \ \
\Longstack{\onslide<3->{\textcolor{red}{2}} \onslide<6->{2}} \ \
\onslide<5->{3} \ \
\stackunder[9pt]{\Longstack{1 \onslide<2->{\textcolor{blue}{1}} \onslide<4->{1} \onslide<6->{1}}}{\Shortstack{. . .}} \ \
\onslide<5->{3} \ \
\Longstack{\onslide<3->{\textcolor{red}{2}} \onslide<6->{2}} \ \
\onslide<5->{3} \ \
\Longstack{1 \onslide<4->{1} \onslide<6->{1}} \ \
\onslide<5->{2} \ \
\Longstack{1 \onslide<6->{1}} \ \
1
}
\begin{document}
```

Edit: I now have the following code, following the advice of user238301.

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}\only<2>{\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}}
\only<4>{\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}}
\only<5>{\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}}
\only<6>{\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}}
1 \ \
\Longstack{1 \onslide<6->{\alert<6>{1}}} \ \
\onslide<5->{\alert<5>{2}} \ \
\Longstack{1 \onslide<4->{\alert<4>{1}} \onslide<6->{\alert<6>{1}}} \ \
\onslide<5->{\alert<5>{3}} \ \
\Longstack{\onslide<3->{\alert<3>{2}} \onslide<6->{\alert<6>{2}}} \ \
\onslide<5->{\alert<5>{3}} \ \
\stackunder[9pt]{\Longstack{1 \onslide<2->{\alert<2>{1}} \onslide<4->{\alert<4>{1}} \onslide<6->{\alert<6>{1}}}}{\Shortstack{. . .}} \ \
\onslide<5->{\alert<5>{3}} \ \
\Longstack{\onslide<3->{\alert<3>{2}} \onslide<6->{\alert<6>{2}}} \ \
\onslide<5->{\alert<5>{3}} \ \
\Longstack{1 \onslide<4->{\alert<4>{1}} \onslide<6->{\alert<6>{1}}} \ \
\onslide<5->{\alert<5>{2}} \ \
\Longstack{1 \onslide<6->{\alert<6>{1}}} \ \
1
\end{center}
\end{frame}
```

This works well, but there are two adjustments I want to make.

1. This animation ends on the blue colors, is it possible to add one more "slide" so that the blue is removed and it ends on black?
2. Is it possible to temporarily bold the colored numbers simultaneously, in the same way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you can use `\alert` to change the color of some text. The initial color is red, so we temporarily set it to blue in the second overlay.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Alert}
\begin{center}\only<2>{\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}}
1 \ \
\Longstack{1 \onslide<6->{1}} \ \
\onslide<5->{2} \ \
\Longstack{1 \onslide<4->{1} \onslide<6->{1}} \ \
\onslide<5->{3} \ \
\Longstack{\onslide<3->{\alert<3>{2}} \onslide<6->{2}} \ \
\onslide<5->{3} \ \
\stackunder[9pt]{\Longstack{1 \onslide<2->{\alert<2>{1}} \onslide<4->{1} \onslide<6->{1}}}{\Shortstack{. . .}} \ \
\onslide<5->{3} \ \
\Longstack{\onslide<3->{\alert<3>{2}} \onslide<6->{2}} \ \
\onslide<5->{3} \ \
\Longstack{1 \onslide<4->{1} \onslide<6->{1}} \ \
\onslide<5->{2} \ \
\Longstack{1 \onslide<6->{1}} \ \
1
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Alert}
\begin{center}\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries}%
\only<2>{\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}}\only<6>{\bfseries}%
1 \ \
\Longstack{1 \onslide<6->{1}} \ \
\onslide<5->{2} \ \
\Longstack{1 \onslide<4->{1} \onslide<6->{1}} \ \
\onslide<5->{3} \ \
\Longstack{\onslide<3->{\alert<3>{2}} \onslide<6->{2}} \ \
\onslide<5->{3} \ \
\stackunder[9pt]{\Longstack{1 \onslide<2->{\alert<2>{1}} \onslide<4->{1} \onslide<6->{1}}}{\Shortstack{. . .}} \ \
\onslide<5->{3} \ \
\Longstack{\onslide<3->{\alert<3>{2}} \onslide<6->{2}} \ \
\onslide<5->{3} \ \
\Longstack{1 \onslide<4->{1} \onslide<6->{1}} \ \
\onslide<5->{2} \ \
\Longstack{1 \onslide<6->{1}} \ \
1
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This works well, there are a couple of adjustments I wanted to make if possible (see edited post). Would you be able to help me modify so it ends on all black numbers, and the colored numbers are temporarily bolded?

Comment: @A.B. I added something along those lines.